# Webclient post call never receiving a response in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, webclient, spring-webclient

I have written a webclient instance in a Java application. I've created a ssl context to use with the server I am trying to hit, as well as basic authentication. I am making a REST Post request. At first I had doubts that I'd properly created the ssl context or that I'd incorrectly added basic authentication. However it seems to me that my post request simply never hits the endpoint, seeing as I haven't been able to print neither the response body, nor the response headers or status code. This makes me think there is something essential unrelated to my code, some sort of configuration perhaps, that is keeping my application from properly sending out the request and hitting the endpoint. Below I have my current code.

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class myApplication {



    public static SslContext getClientSslContext() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        //log.info("Creating SslContext for webClientBuilder");
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("myPath"),
                ("myPassword").toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("myPath"),
                ("myPassword").toCharArray());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, ("myPassword").toCharArray());
        //log.info("Created SslContext for webClientBuilder");
        return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
                .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
                .build();
    }


    static Mono<ClientResponse> createBackUpRequest() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //JSONObject reqBodyJson = new JSONObject();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> reqBody
                = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> variables
                = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();


        reqBody.put("variables", variables);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(reqBody));

        SslContext sslContext = getClientSslContext();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslSpec -> sslSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                //.baseUrl("host")
                .defaultHeaders(HttpHeaders -> HttpHeaders.setBasicAuth("myUser", "myPassword"))
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Spring 5 WebClient")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                .build();

        return webClient.post()
                .uri("host")
                .body(Mono.just(reqBody), LinkedHashMap.class)//if directly putting the map doesn't work
                .exchange()
                .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> System.out.println("clientResponse.headers() = " + clientResponse.headers()))
                .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> System.out.println("clientResponse.statusCode() = " + clientResponse.statusCode()));
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        SpringApplication.run(QaAutomatedBackupApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("print out");
        createBackUpRequest();
        System.out.println("second print out");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be needed to get help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never subscribe to the Reactive stream.

Nothing happens until you subscribe. What you've done in `createBackUpRequest` is build up a plan (`Mono`) for how to get `ClientResponse` data.

Change your main method to

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        SpringApplication.run(QaAutomatedBackupApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("print out");
        createBackUpRequest().subscribe(response -> 
            System.out.println("second print out")
        );
    }
```

Then it will actually make the web request. Otherwise the plan will never be executed.
Bare in mind that if your Spring Boot app is not a Spring Web app (which will continue to run on other threads, listening for web requests), it will just exit immediately before waiting for the stream to complete.

If that is the case and you just want to test and experiment, you can put a `Thread.sleep(10000)` at the end, so that it has time to execute the web request before the app closes. But obviously that's not a good real world implementation.